# Illustrator: How to alter text in perspective?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, perspective

I have maybe a somewhat silly question: I used a tutorial to place multiple pieces of text into perspective (e.g., [tutorial](https://medialoot.com/blog/how-to-easily-make-perspective-text-in-illustrator/)).

Once in perspective, I would like to change the text; however, the text does not seem to behave as texts anymore. Rather it seems like 'a figure'. I have tried to select the text with the "Perspective selection tool" but without any luck.

**Question**

How do you alter the text that is put in perspective in Illustrator?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

If you click the above button or if you double-click the text using the 'v' tool you should get a blue text box that you can edit normally using the text tool. Then press 'esc' to get back to normal view.

[image]

Comment: Oh, you're right! I didn't even bother trying to double-click because the text looks so expanded with [anchor points and all](https://i.imgur.com/Btr2pKj.png). Even shows the outline in outline mode.

Comment: Yeah I just looked at it and thought the same at first. Already was thinking maybe with 3D extrude as workaround. But then found this out as I more or less accidentally double-clicked on the perspective text.

Comment: That seems to be the solution, thanks! However, (a newbie as I am) I cannot seem to find these perspective object icons? Where can I find them? Or how can I make them appear? Thanks!

Comment: Click on the text. It should look like the image from Wolff when you click the first time. When you click again (or click the icons that appear in the top left) you should see something like the image I posted in the solution.

Comment: Ah thanks, that seems to work! I seem to have messed up the cartoon by grouping things or something... I found that text can be edited via the menu also (Object -> Perspective -> Text ...). In my case, it is gray (unclickable). But your answer still works for normal text!

Answer (score 5):

If you simply want quick perspective, *without* the entire "lock to Perspective Grid" thing*, and keep text live and editable.....

I'd use **Envelope Distort**.

- Set the text, or whatever objects/groups you wish to have in perspective, and select it/them
- Choose `Object > Envelope Distort > Make with Warp`
- Choose **any** of the `Style` options - it *doesn't matter* which you use.
- Set the `Bend` to **0%**
- Then adjust the `Horizontal` or `Vertical` under the `Distortion` options to your liking

[image]

For opposing perspectives, merely use `+` and `-` values for the distortion...

[image]

You can still edit text as *live text* by choosing `Object > Envelope Distort > Edit Contents` Although any edited text is still going to adhere to the overall envelope shape. So, drastic changes to text are often better handled by merely recreating the envelope on a new text object.

---

<sub>*Full disclosure: I've always found the Perspective Grid to be overall cumbersome and very user **un**friendly. 
But that's me. `:)`</sub>

Comment: Completely agree – never really use perspective grid. I tend to use the 'free transform tool'  with 'Free Distort' option .

Comment: Free transform's great.. but not for Live Text if you want it to remain *live text*. `:)`